Nav2 bringup not launching if namespace is passed as an argument
I am trying to launch nav2 bringup to perform navigation in a gazebo simulation. This was working initially, but now when I launch the nav2_bringup
 ros2 launch nav2_bringup bringup_launch.py  map:="/home/sriram/Desktop/study/diff_drive_ws/src/sim/maps/room_april_tag.yaml" params_file:="/home/sriram/Desktop/study/diff_drive_ws/src/sim/params/nav2_params.yaml" namespace:="robot001" use_sim_time:=true

it is not launched correctly. The terminal window is stuck at
enter code here[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/sriram/.ros/log/2024-05-27-18-04-41-266462-sriram-34123
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [component_container_isolated-1]: process started with pid [34136]

Node graph has only two nodes, nav2_container and launch_ros_{some number}. Am I missing something here, as the same launch command was working a while ago. I also get an error when I terminate the launch (ctrl + c)
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): cannot use Destroyable because destruction was requested
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): cannot use Destroyable because destruction was requested

Edit: Removing the namespace argument from the launch command solved the issue. Is there any alternative way to add namespace to the launch?

The full bringup example is the tb3_simulation_launch.py, I'd start there :-)

The full example launches fine, but fails to launch with any custom parameters. Is there anything wrong with the launch command?
